# Using FullCalendar on React without Jquery UI Draggable for external drag drop

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I try to drag-drop external div to fullcalendar in React to create event.

But React isn't compatible with JQuery UI so I cannot use draggable.

Using react-big-calendar is big move, so I try to seek if there's easier solution to use fullcalendar that I've been using in the past years.

I also tried to use react-dnd but the fullcalendar's drop is never called.

Anyone has suggestion? thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. For the moment it is difficult to tell from your question what exactly you have tried. Ideally you show your efforts in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this makes it easiest for others to reproduce and subsequently (hopefully) solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply Erik =). I folowed  https://codepen.io/kotazi/pen/KVoXob but it said that draggable is not a function. Then I follow this https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/master/examples/01%20Dustbin/Single%20Target by wrapping fullcalendar inside the target but fullcalendar.drop event is never called. Is that make sense?

Comment: Are you importing your Calendar like
import FullCalendar  from '@fullcalendar/react'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. For whatever reason, there doesn't seem to be any docs on react + draggable events. fwiw, I hacked it together and got it to work like this in an unholy union of react and plain DOM manipulation. Here's my abbreviated code.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

...

export default function Sidebar(props: SidebarProps) {
    const { workOrders } = useWorkOrders()
    const [draggableInitialized, setDraggableInitialized] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const element = document.getElementById('workOrderContainer')

        if (element && workOrders.length > 0 && !draggableInitialized) {
            setDraggableInitialized(true)

            new Draggable(element, {
                itemSelector: '.draggable-event',
                eventData: (eventElement) => {
                    const workOrderId = eventElement.id

                    return {
                        ... your data here
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }, [workOrders, draggableInitialized])

    return (
              <span id="workOrderContainer" >
                  {workOrders.map((workOrder) => (
                          <span key={workOrder.id} className="draggable-event" id={String(workOrder.id)} >
                              <WorkOrder key={workOrder.id} title={workOrder.title} />
                          </span>
                      ))}
              </span>
    )
}
```